# Android change webview content at a specific time or date regularly

Tags: android, android-webview, alarmmanager

I have a very simple webview layout.

I would like to change the webview content every 1 hour.

Tried to use

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com");
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    context.startActivity(in);
```

in the broadcast receiver, but failed.....

Any sugguestions? Thanks!!!!

the main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private int page;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
    findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    showeb("http://www.google.com");

    Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class);
    intent.setAction("repeating");
    PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent
        .getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

    long firstime=SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
            , firstime, 3600*1000, sender);


}

private void showeb(String string) {
    WebView engine = (WebView) (findViewById(R.id.webView1));
    engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    engine.loadUrl(string);

}
```

and the receiver class

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "short alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com");
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        context.startActivity(in);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to update WebView which is already in foreground (that is currently being displayed) then you can periodically call `webview.loadUrl` simply using `java.util.TimerTask`

```
    private Timer webViewUpdater;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        webViewUpdater = new Timer();
        webViewUpdater.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        showeb("http://www.yahoo.com")
                    }
                });
            }
        }, firsttime, 3600*1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        webViewUpdater.cancel();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but where should I put these codes? and can I set the webview to change at a specific day and time? (e.g. Monday 5pm) thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: you just need to override onResume() method of your Activity. It's OK to leave periodical check in the code and then compare to your Mon, 5PM and do reload if necessary.